# how to clear value in viewmodel in kendo ui if bound value is not present in drop-down option

Tags: mvvm, kendo-ui

I have a viewmodel which I am binding to a drop-down. I want to clear the value form the viewmodel if that value is not present in the drop-down options.

Any help on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding your problem. Can you show some code?

Comment: I have created a jsfiddle sample http://jsfiddle.net/5GGVf/162/ view model selected id is 5 which is not present in options of drop-down, in this case i want my viewmodel's value to be cleared.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want the drop-down to be in a unselected state. This is not really supported, have a look at this reply by Iliana http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-web/dropdownlist/dropdownlist---how-to-clear-selection.aspx#T3QRJoe8v0yfnVlw3IzWdw  But, you can add an empty option to your data and then have that selected. http://jsfiddle.net/amomsen/99gNv/

Answer (score 0):

I think a better way to go about this is to actually use a ComboBox. http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/combobox 
Which allows an unselected state.

```
$("#products").kendoComboBox({
                   dataTextField: "text",
                   dataValueField: "value",
                   dataSource: data
              })
              .closest(".k-widget")
              .attr("id", "products_wrapper");
```

And then clearing the value from the combo box when its not present in the data set.

```
var combobox = $("#products").data("kendoComboBox");
combobox.text("");
```

Have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/amomsen/UKfz6/3/

Comment: if user doesnot enter anything in the combobox it will not clear the value form viewmodel

Comment: Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: validating it on server side itself, so if value is not present in list then it will be empty.